# Looking for a way to change http request and add user id on body data

Tags: .net-core

I am working on a web API where login is required in order to do any other action, so I am using identity with role-based authentication. 
What I would like to achieve is to override the user id into the request body before the controller's action only in cases where the request type implements a certain interface.

For example, I have these view model

```
public class UserVM : IVMLogging {
    public Guid? ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public Guid Role { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class OptionVM : IVMLogging {
    public Guid? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And this interface

```
public interface IVMLogging {
    string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

In both cases property LastModifiedBy is where I want store the user id (ignoring the value coming from client).

Is this possible to be done?

Answer (score 0):

While you can use middleware to modify an inbound request on the way to the controller, the work to try to inspect, serialize, and deserialize the body type is probably more trouble than it's worth. Your controllers can modify the contents of the view model on return if there are any properties that you'd like to update, like attaching the user:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(Foo foo)
        {
            foo.Qux = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;   // Use the identity name
            foo.Qux = HttpContext.User.FindFirst("claimName").Value;    // grab a claim value
            // do whatever actions
        }
        ...
```

Your controller will have access to the HTTP context and can grab the current identity or claims and add them where you want them before you process your viewmodel.

If this is something you find yourself doing regularly, you could add an extension for it for your interface:

```
    public static class FooExtensions
    {
        public static IFoo SetFooUser(this IFoo foo, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            foo.Qux = claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name;
            return foo;
        }
    }
```

Which can then be called more simply with `foo.SetFooUser(HttpContext.User)` in your controller as long as it implements the interface.